# Objective-C++ block vs Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c++, objective-c-blocks

In Objective-C I have the valid code:

TestTwo.h:

```
@interface TestTwo : NSObject
-(void)test;
@end
```

TestTwo.m:

```
@implementation TestTwo
-(void)test
{
    void (^d_block)(void) = 
    ^{
        int n;
    };
}
@end
```

What I really want is an Objective-C++ class that defines a method similar to `test`. This is simplification, but illustrates the intent. So, in Objective-C++ I have:

Test.h:

```
class Test
{
public:
    void TestIt();
};
```

Test.mm:

```
#include "Test.h"

void Test::TestIt()
{
    void (^d_block)(void) = 
    ^{
        int n;
    };
}
```

I get the following error:

> error: 'int Test::n' is not a static member of 'class Test'.

If I remove `int n;` there is no error. How do I define `n` within the block in this context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [a GCC bug filed under radar #8953986](http://lists.apple.com/archives/xcode-users/2011/Mar/msg00255.html). You can either use Clang/LLVM 2.0+ to compile your code as is, or put your block variables in the global name space (i.e., `int ::n`) and use GCC. Note that using the global name space in this case is not valid C++ and Clang/LLVM 2.0+ won’t compile it.

Comment: Switching to the LLVM compiler seems to do the trick. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Within the class definition you can add:

```
private:
static int n;
```

Comment: Hmmm. I suppose if I have to I can do that. But, I'm looking for a way to define a variable scoped to the block. Is that not possible?