# Variable is not a static member of class

Tags: objective-c, ios, objective-c++

I'm working on a GameKitHelper class, and it's mostly written in C++, but with Objective-C in some places as well, inside an .mm file.

I removed a bit of functionality to isolate the error:

```
void GameKitHelper::PopulateFriendScores(DynArray<GameCenterScore> *FriendScores)
{
    GKLeaderboard *leaderboardRequest = [[GKLeaderboard alloc] init];
    if (leaderboardRequest != nil)
    {
        leaderboardRequest.playerScope = GKLeaderboardPlayerScopeFriendsOnly;
        leaderboardRequest.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
        leaderboardRequest.range = NSMakeRange(1,25);

        [leaderboardRequest loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) 
         {
             int i = 0;
             printf("%d", i);
         }];
    }
}
```

The error I get here is:

```
'int GameKitHelper::i' is not a static member of 'class GameKitHelper'
```

Comment: Is that the **exact** code?  Which line is the error message referring to?

Comment: it's referring to the 'int i = 0;' line, which also causes another error for the next line dealing with 'i' not being defined, though not very relevant.  And yes, it's the exact code, minus the old code which I had commented out when testing this simpler way to produce the problem.

Comment: I've seen plenty of examples doing the same thing, so I guess the question might be more along the lines of not what I'm doing wrong in the given code, but any ideas how this problem could occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a gcc bug. See [Objective-C++ block vs Objective-C block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6525928/objective-c-block-vs-objective-c-block) for one of many reports of it.

<soapbox>I recommend avoiding Objective-C++ as much as possible. It's slow to compile, bloated to run (particularly with ARC since it turns on [-fobjc-arc-exceptions](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)), buggy in the compiler and the debugger, and mostly a mess in my experience giving the worst of both worlds. C++ is fine. Objective-C is fine. Just keep the interface between them as small as possible. </soapbox>

But switching to clang 2.0 might fix this specific problem.

Comment: Thanks, switching to LLVM 2.0 did the trick.  Thanks for the general advice as well.

Answer (score 1):

In case it might help someone else...

I am required by the needs of my project to use the 10.6 SDK and LLVM-gcc 4.2. I cannot require clang for the code to compile.

I worked around this problem by declaring my variable as a shared_ptr in the parent function... putting the actual object I need on the heap. In the block, I access the object through the shared_ptr variable. This arrangement causes the shared_ptr to be implicitly copied into the block while the copy in the parent function is free to be released. Since I am not declaring a variable in the block, I bypass the bug.

I used a preprocessor check to use a normal stack variable if the code is building on clang or some other compiler.