# Obj-C++: template metafunction for recognizing Objective-C classes?

Tags: objective-c, templates, objective-c++

Using Objective-C++, can I write a C++ `IsObjectiveCClass<T>` template metafunction such that `IsObjectiveCClass<T>::value` is true if and only if T is an Objective-C class?

Exactly what are ObjC classes from the viewpoint of the C / C++ subset of the language? When used in a C / C++ context, MyClass* pointers seem to behave like ordinary C pointers; does that mean that MyClass is also a C type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a simplistic solution that should work in most (if not all? Can anyone think of when this might fail?) cases (it uses clang 3.0 via xcode 4.2 - use typedefs instead of using aliases for earlier clang versions):

```
template<class T> struct IsObjectiveCClass 
{ 
  using yesT = char (&)[10];
  using noT = char (&)[1];
  static yesT choose(id);
  static noT choose(...);
  static T make();
  enum { value = sizeof(choose(make())) == sizeof(yesT) }; 

};
```

Comment: Ah, that's what I didn't think of: the fact that any MyClass* can be implicitly converted to id. Nice, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can read my most recent rant about ObjC++ in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7031540/variable-is-not-a-static-member-of-class/7034585#7034585). Avoid it as much as you can possibly get away with. Definitely don't try to integrate Objective-C into C++ template metaprogramming. The compiler might actually rip a hole in space.

Hyperbole aside, what you're trying to do is likely impossible. Objective-C classes are just structs. (C++ classes actually just structs too.) There's not much compile-time introspection available.

An `id` is a C pointer to a `struct objc_object`. At runtime, every object is an `id`, no matter its class.

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

Comment: I wouldn't call it impossible - see my answer below.  And Objective C++0x using clang 3.0 is a very cool language - although I admit I haven't used it for any large project yet.

Comment: This fact actually makes it easy: since all objective-c pointer addressees are of type `struct objc_object`, whose (albiet private) definition idiomatically must contain an `isa_t isa` member – I personally found `objc_object::isa` quite good enough for SFINAE e.g. `objc::traits::is_object<T>`; see: https://github.com/fish2000/libimread/blob/master/include/libimread/objc-rt.hh#L499-L516 Further reading: http://unixjunkie.blogspot.de/2006/02/nil-and-nil.html plus the objc runtime source – http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/objc4/objc4-647/runtime/objc-private.h

Answer (score 3):

As with the accepted answer, you can test whether the type is convertible to id, in C++17:

```
template <typename T>
struct is_objc_ptr : std::integral_constant<bool, 
  std::is_convertible_v<T, id> && !std::is_null_pointer_v<T>> {};
template <typename T>
constexpr bool is_objc_ptr_v = is_objc_ptr<T>::value;
```

Testing:

```
static_assert(!is_objc_ptr_v<nullptr_t>);
static_assert(!is_objc_ptr_v<int>);
static_assert(!is_objc_ptr_v<char *>);
static_assert(is_objc_ptr_v<id>);
static_assert(is_objc_ptr_v<NSObject *>);
```

I don't know of a way to discover ObjC inheritance relationships at compile-time; in theory they're changeable at runtime so you would have to query the runtime.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the implementation of the C++ STL library in Xcode, you can follow the template specialization models of others like `std::is_integral` or `std::is_floating_point`:

```
template <class T> struct isObjcObject     : public std::false_type { };
template <>        struct isObjcObject<id> : public std::true_type { };
```

where `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` are defined in the `<type_traits>` header file.

If for whatever reason you don't have `std::false_type` and `std::true_type` (depending on your C++ version), you can define them yourself as such:

```
template<bool B>   struct boolean_constant { static constexpr const bool value = B; };

template <class T> struct isObjcObject     : public boolean_constant<false> { };
template <>        struct isObjcObject<id> : public boolean_constant<true> { };
```

Note that you can also do this for Objective-C classes too:

```
template <class T> struct isObjcClass        : public std::false_type { };
template <>        struct isObjcClass<Class> : public std::true_type { };
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a template specialisation for 'id' and 'NSObject*', but you'll always be working against the language because the ObjC type system is *not* the C++ type system.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Doug's answer, but slightly simpler:

```
template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool is_objc_v = std::is_convertible_v<id,T>;
```

Checking that `id` is convertible to `T` – instead of the other way around – avoids false positives for C++ types which have a user-defined implicit conversion to an Obj-C type.