# Using C++ Type Trait For Objective-C++

Tags: c++, objective-c, templates, type-traits

AFAIK, developers can use C++ type trait to know the "type" of class and relation ship between classes. Some of them is implemented by the compiler.

For example, `std::is_base_of<b, d>::value` return true if `b` is the base class of `d`. And it's implemented by `__is_base_of`.

And there are some tricks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040438/obj-c-template-metafunction-for-recognizing-objective-c-classes).

Now I'm trying to find the rules for ObjC Classes.

As for test code:

```
@interface Super : NSObject
@end
@implementation Super
@end

@interface SubA : Super
@end
@implementation SubA
@end

@interface SubB : Super
@end
@implementation SubB
@end

int main()
{
    NSLog(@"SubA is base of Super %d", std::is_base_of<SubA, Super>::value);
    NSLog(@"SubA* is base of Super* %d", std::is_base_of<SubA*, Super*>::value);
    NSLog(@"Super is base of SubA %d", std::is_base_of<Super, SubA>::value);
    NSLog(@"Super* is base of SubA* %d", std::is_base_of<Super*, SubA*>::value);


    NSLog(@"SubA is convertible of Super %d", std::is_convertible<SubA, Super>::value);
    NSLog(@"SubA* is convertible of Super* %d", std::is_convertible<SubA*, Super*>::value);
    NSLog(@"Super is convertible of SubA %d", std::is_convertible<Super, SubA>::value);
    NSLog(@"Super* is convertible of SubA* %d", std::is_convertible<Super*, SubA*>::value);

    NSLog(@"SubA is convertible of SubB %d", std::is_convertible<SubA, SubB>::value);
    NSLog(@"SubA* is convertible of SubB* %d", std::is_convertible<SubA*, SubB*>::value);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
SubA is base of Super 0
SubA* is base of Super* 0
Super is base of SubA 0
Super* is base of SubA* 0
SubA is convertible of Super 0
SubA* is convertible of Super* 1
Super is convertible of SubA 0
Super* is convertible of SubA* 1
SubA is convertible of SubB 0
SubA* is convertible of SubB* 0
```

This output is out of my expected. Since all ObjC classes are base of a C struct `objc_class`, I think all `std::is_base_of` between ObjcC classes should be false and all `std::is_convertible` should be true.

So what is the principle inside? And what rules should I followed while using C++ type trait for objc classes?